# Azure App Service Web app deploy puts files in wrong folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I am just getting to grips with deploying my asp.net application via release pipeline in Azure Devops.

Previously, I have been deploying my web app directly from Visual Studio using publish which works fine.

But when i have set this up in a Release pipline in Azure dev ops it doesnt work, when i try and load the page i just get:

'You do not have permission to view this directory or page'

and looking at the deployed files via Server Explorer I can see the files are in a 'Drop' folder

[image]

But when looking at the deployed files when deployed directly from VS it looks like:

[image]

I know this must be down to how I have configured either my build or release pipeline but i cannot see where.

[image]

Release pipeline

[image]

I see here that i set the path to the Drop folder, but i added that as without it it was failing....i think

Comment: That's the build side of your pipeline - I bet if you looked at the `Publish Artifact` step, that would explain the `drop` folder, as that's the default artifact publish location. The question now becomes, what is your release pipeline doing? Can you post a screenshot of the deploy step in your release?

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole have updated as above.  Im just going to run it without the path mapped to Drop